# Define timeout when tox is installing requirements

Tags: python, gitlab, tox

I have a gitlab ci pipeline which basically do some stuff on the enviornment ( install python and other packages) then it simply run `tox` in order to run some tests.

```
stages:
  - check



before_script:
    # here you can run any commands before the pipelines start
    - apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y python3.9
    - apt-get install -y libpq-dev &&  apt-get install -y python3.9-dev
    - apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y gcc && apt-get install -y postgresql
    - apt-get install -y  postgresql-contrib && apt-get install -y  ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6
    - apt-get install -y git
    - pip install tox



check:
  stage: check
  image: gitlab.*****.com:****/*****
  environment: prod
  services:
    - name: docker:19.03.8-dind #20.10.7
      alias: docker
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - |
      echo "
      machine gitlab.*****.com
      login gitlab-ci-token
      password $CI_JOB_TOKEN
      " > ~/.netrc 
    - tox
```

This is my `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist =
    {python3.9}


[testenv]
passenv = *
setenv =
    AIRFLOW_HOME = /airflow_home
deps=
    pytest
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt 
commands=
    pytest
```

The problem is that when `tox` is building the env and installing the packages specified in the `requirements.txt` it returns a `ReadTimeOutError`.

I've tried to delete `tox` and simply run a `pip install -r requiremenets --default-timeout=200` and it worked.
So the problem seems to be a timeout.
I'd like to define a `timeout` but i don't want to discard tox.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tox is using pip under the hood, so you can use the same options, preferable as environment variables.

So, following https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables you need to convert `--default-timeout` into the  `PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` variable.

You can use this variable either by setting it in CI and then use the `passenv` directive in your `tox.ini`, or you can set it directly in `tox.ini` via the `setenv` directive.

Relevant documentation for tox:

- https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#pass_env
- https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#set_env

Comment: Thanks for the help, i didn't see it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change default [`install_command`](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#install_command):

```
install_command = pip install {opts} --default-timeout=200 {packages}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether this works with the latest version 4 of tox? I saw quite some issues reported on the tox issue tracker that mentioned that the pip options did not work any more.

Comment: @JürgenGmach Nope, I still use Python 2.7 and 3.4+ so I use tox 3.

Comment: @JürgenGmach But it's listed in the latest docs (not even marked deprecated) so I do not expect any problem in `tox4`.